# Exception in Alpakka JsonReader substream not being caught by supervisor

Tags: scala, stream, akka, akka-stream, alpakka

I have a source which uses a `flatMapConcat` to consolidate a new stream of elements, produced by parsing Json. To do this, I am using JsonReader provided by Alpakka (https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/data-transformations/json.html). This works well, but I would like to handle the case where invalid Json is presented to the reader. In this case I would like the exception to bubble up to the supervisor so it can restart the stream.

Here's a quick snippet showcasing the bad json case:

```
val systemErrorHandler: Supervision.Decider = {
  case e: Exception =>
    println("System Error")
    Supervision.Restart
  case _ => Supervision.Stop
}

val routeErrorHandler: Supervision.Decider = { 
  case e: Exception =>
    println("Route Error")
    Supervision.Restart
}

val exceptionStrategy = ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(routeErrorHandler)

implicit val actorSystem: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
implicit val materializer: Materializer = ActorMaterializer(ActorMaterializerSettings(actorSystem).withSupervisionStrategy(systemErrorHandler))


val json = """{"test":"one}"""

val route = Source.single("1").flatMapConcat { _ =>
  Source.single(ByteString(json))
    .via(JsonReader.select("$")).map(_.utf8String)
}.to(Sink.foreach(println)).withAttributes(exceptionStrategy)

route.run
```

I would expect JsonReader, upon throwing an exception, to fail the stage and then bubble the exception up to the `routeErrorHandler`. However, when run the JsonReader stage is failed and the exception is swallowed. I also attempted to place a `recover` in the stream to throw the exception at a 'higher' level (outside the substream) but that also doesn't get handled with either the routeErrorHandler supervisor or the supervisor placed on the ActorMaterializer.

Is this expected behavior? If so, what is the proper way to ensure an exception within a substream reaches the supervisor strategy?

Comment: Did you find a solution? The errors are propagated to from the substream to the main stream correctly. Here is a [test for that](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/5a4ec8a5575fc3012011b046d64c39cc6fc3fcf8/akka-stream-tests/src/test/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/FlowFlattenMergeSpec.scala#L93-L101). So either the `JsonReader.select` fails in a strange way, or the exception is handled by yet another supervision strategy. Did you try adding supervision strategy attrbute on the substream?

Comment: I opted to change the source to return an Either, and then handle the error outside the Source. Based on the source code (https://github.com/akka/alpakka/blob/master/json-streaming/src/main/scala/akka/stream/alpakka/json/impl/JsonStreamReader.scala) it seems like the JsonReader stage just fails on an exception which makes sense. I can't think why the error wouldn't bubble up into one of the two supervisors present. Yes, I did try adding the supervision strategy attribute on the substream to no avail